# Impact of Enabling UDP Checksum (IPv4) on the System

Tags: ipv4, udp, checksum

AFAIK, UDP checksum is an optional feature on IPv4.

I want to enable it on a gateway (IPv4), but I want to know if it has any negative impact on the system, e.g., increasing CPU utilization or increasing signaling traffic?

Answer (score 0):

UDP checksums aren't any of the gateway's business unless the gateway is doing NAPT, in which case the gateway *must* fix the checksum of any UDP datagram that has one set, if the gateway had to translate a port number in the UDP header, because that throws off the checksum. The CPU impact of correcting UDP checksums during NAPT is immeasurably small.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken gateways are L4 devices that are in charge of constructing L4 segments, e.g., UDP segments. I'm simply asking if checksum computations have a negative impact on them?